# Syncing data from web service upon launch?

Tags: ios, push-notification

How can I run my app while syncing data from web service upon launch?

My code looks like

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

However, the app crashes before it launched.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you don't put so many processes on you AppDelegate class, especially on the **AppDelegate** method `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

You can create a

> ViewController

Where you can put all the processes -methods that syncs your data.
You may use, JSON, XML web services to integrate with your data on external database, and store it on either of the following:

> Code Data
>   PList
>   User Defaults (NSUserDefaults)

whichever fits your need.

Comment: Additionally, on you ViewController, this may display an image contained on a UIImageView, this image may contain an image similar to your Launch Image or an HUD showing that you are trying connect to your server.